# SAS date operation within proc sql

Tags: sas, proc-sql

I'm very new to SAS, and am trying to modify this piece of code

```
proc sql;
select a, Current_Date - 2 - b as some_date
from table
```

Current_Date is a function in sas. I'm trying to replace it with my own date. a and b are column names in a database i'm connecting to. I tried changing Current_Date to '12nov2013'd, but it doesn't seem to work.

I tried:

1.

```
%let startFrom = '12nov2013'd;
proc sql;
  select a, &startFrom - 2 - b as some_date
from table
```

this doesn't work.

2.

```
proc sql;
  select a, input('12nov2013',date9.) - 2 - b as some_date
from table
```

This doesn't work

How should Ii do this date operation in SAS

3.

```
proc sql;
  select a, intck('DAY','19nov2015'd,rqo_tran_date_alt) as TranMonth
from table
```

this also doesn't work

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?  Gives an error? Gives incorrect answer? What answer?  Would be helpful to provide example input dataset and example results/desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing really wrong with your first example, though it could be improved.

```
%let startFrom = '12nov2013'd;

data have;
  input a $ b;
  datalines;
Zero 0
Five 5
Ten 10
Hundred 100
;;;;
run;


proc sql;
  select a, &startFrom - 2 - b as some_date format=date9.
  from have;
quit;
```

Adding the format is pretty helpful usually, though not required.  This assumes `b` is a *numeric* variable containing a *number of days*.  If it contains anything else, or is character, this won't necessarily give you the correct result.